# Is the suggested answer in the book wrong? (sign diagram)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The function is as follows

$-2x^3+6x-4$
[image]

The sign diagram for that in the book is as follows: 
[image]

As seen on the pic and graph it is only positive before -2, NOT after 1. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Which tool do you use to plot this inequality?

Comment: wolframalpha :)

Comment: You are correct that it is not positive for $x\gt1$.

Comment: I was unsure because the sign diagram for the derivative would be sort the inverse of this and that had a nice symmetry to it.

Comment: You can know there's something wrong with the book's diagram even without plotting, because a polynomial of odd degree will always have different signs for $x\to\infty$ and $x\to-\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the book seems to be wrong. The most likely explanation is that they found roots at $x  = -2$ and $x = 1$, but didn't realize that the second one doesn't actually change the sign of the function.